# MySQL Order By Query for varchar saved date

Tags: mysql

I try to order the results of a query by the date which is in the format `yyyy/mm/dd` and I am using this query to no avail.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%y/%m/%d')
```

I can't change the type of field that the date is stored in so I am hoping I can order the date post data entry.

Any help and advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date is in that format, you don't need to convert it to a date, surely? That format would sort alphabetically, assuming it is 0 padded... (i.e. July is 3 July 2012 is 2012/07/03...)

So you can just go:

```
select * from table order by date
```

What type of field is your `date` field: are you sure it is a `varchar`?

Assuming it is a `varchar`, you can work out what is going wrong by going:

```
select str_to_date(date, '%y/%m/%d') from table
```

You (should) get all NULL's, because the `%y` is wrong. Try:

```
select str_to_date(date, '%Y/%m/%d') from table
```

and it should work. But as noted, you don't have to convert to sort.

Comment: +1 Because the choice of this date format is usually specifically done because it is naturally sorted (which doesn't mean it's the right choice in a DB which offers date formats).

Answer (score 0):

Try with capital Y:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y/%m/%d')`

Lowercase Y is for yy, uppercase for yyyy.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date